# Why does my FTP client prompt me to replace files I haven't transferred yet?

Tags: ftp

Let's say I'm downloading a website to my computer via FTP. In my FTP client, I select all of the files and folders in the website's root folder and begin downloading them to an empty folder on my desktop. Halfway through the transfer, I'm interrupted by a prompt asking me whether I want to replace such-and-such file or folder. Why does this happen?

It's just something that I've noticed over the years. And I never know what the right answer is when I'm in the middle of transferring thousands of files. I usually say "yes", but then I doubt the integrity of the copy. It happens sporadically when I'm downloading or when I'm uploading. I assume it's not a bug in my FTP client (FileZilla), or else it's a very, very persistent bug.

Edit: OK, so my question was switftly and mercilessly closed as off topic. Where should I have posted it? Can it be moved there?

Answer (score 2):

This may happen if you're using windows locally, and linux remotely.

Since linux allows for case sensitive filenames, and windows does not. Your FTP may have files like "Images.jpg" and "images.jpg" and "IMAGES.jpg", but all three of these are the same to windows, so you will be prompted to overwrite them when more than one of them is downloaded.